# AngularFire2 upload multiple files and get an array of the download URls

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

I want to upload multiple files and then return the relative URLs in an array using angularFire2, for that I created a list of Observable in a service file then subscribed to it using `combineLatest()` on the component but I am not able to get the results. Since `downloadURL()` is not available anymore on the task I am struggling to return the final result array.

chat.service.ts

```
uploadMessageFiles(filesList, roomId: string) {
    const downloadUrls$ = filesList.map((file) => {
      let fileName = this.db.createPushId();
      fileName+= file.name;
      const filePath = `/chat-files/${roomId}/${fileName}`;
      const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
      const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);


      return task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
       // missing logic
      );
    });

    return downloadUrls$;
  }
```

chat.component.ts

```
let dowloadObservable = this.chatService.uploadMessageFiles(
        this.selectedFiles,
        this.selectedRoom.id
      );

      combineLatest(...dowloadObservable).subscribe((downloadURLs) => {
       //get URLs
      });
```

I need to subscribe and get the result on the component because I have an other logic there I can't treat the data by subscribing directly to `task.snapshotChanges()`
I believe that the bast way to get the dowload URL is:
`task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => downloadURL = this.storage.ref(path).getDownloadURL() )
 )
.subscribe()`
But I can't manage to return the URL as the result of the Observable susbcription using finalize and pipe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with firebase, so this might need a little adjustment because I can't tell from your code where observables are being returned vs static data; but here goes...

Instead of having `uploadMessageFiles` return an array of observables (*which you later need to combine*), you can have it return a single observable that emits an array that contains the results of all of the individual uploads.

[`from`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from) will create an observable that emits each item from your array. You can then use the [`mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) operator to make the service call for each file and emit their results. Last, you can use the [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) operator to combine all of the emissions into a single array.

Something like this could work:

```
public uploadMessageFiles(filesList, roomId: string) {
    return from(filesList).pipe(
      mergeMap(file => {
        const fileName = this.db.createPushId() + file.name;
        const filePath = `/chat-files/${roomId}/${fileName}`;
        const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
        const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);

        return task.snapshotChanges();
      }),
      map(changes => // return url from changes //),
      scan((allUrls, url) => [...allUrls, url], [])
    );
  }
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-combine-multiple-call-results-to-array?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgeneric.service.ts) of a simplified sample.